# Javascript injection Prevention: where do I start?

Tags: asp.net, security, javascript-injection

I'm working on a new web site (ASP.NET, Web Forms, C#) and need to include protection against Javascript injection attacks. Does anyone have any good links for how to implement a site secure against these types of attacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to deploy proper **input valdiation** on anything you read in from your clients.

OWASP has a great summary of this here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet

Basically, you're going to want to build up a whitelist (normally some regexs for everything that users should be able to sent/submit to your application) and then only accept the whitelist. A good practice is to do this, but throw a blacklist in front of the whitelist Basically, look for known-bad things like Javascript script tags, and reject them (this is the blacklist part). Then pass what got though there to make sure content that you should be seeing and can safely handle and only allow it though if it is.

Comment: What purpose does the blacklist serve if the whitelist is well designed (after all, regexes to filter out `<script>` tags can usually be defeated quite easily).

Comment: Kill things you know are bad right away. If things are obviously bad, don't spend cycles running them through what can be a complex whitelist with lots of regexs and rules. The blacklist should be very small and only include the things you know are very bad and you'd never want to see (script tags for example). There is also a usecase where you'd have a global blacklist (none of my apps should ever accept these as they are very dangerous) and a per-app whitelist (tailed to that app's acceptable inputs).

Comment: Ah okay, so it's basically for performance, rather than security. It makes sense in that context, but only if it could be left away without affecting the program's robustness against dangerous input.

Comment: Performance is a good motivator. I'll also submit that it provides a double check against known-bad inputs, so an error in your whitelist implementation doesn't let bad stuff in...it's a measure of Defense in Depth, which is always a good idea.

Comment: I agree, the more layers of defense, the better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-site scripting (XSS) is the name of the vulnerability you are concerned about. [Read up on it at OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) and consult their [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

While you are there, have a browse through their [Top Ten most common web application vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_Ten) and consider other attacks/weaknesses you need to protect yourself from.